# Read in lines of text file to separate arrays using indexOf

Tags: java, indexof

I want to separate the elements of a text file into different arrays based of whether or not the line contains a question mark. Here is as far as I got.

```
    Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String file_name;
    System.out.print("What is the full file path name?\n>>");
    file_name = inScan.next();

    Scanner fScan = new Scanner(new File(file_name));
    ArrayList<String> Questions = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> Other = new ArrayList();

    while (fScan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        if(fScan.nextLine.indexOf("?"))
        {
            Questions.add(fScan.nextLine());
        }

        Other.add(fScan.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: indexOf returns an integer, so you don't seem to have even compiled the code. what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: java requires `booleans` in `if` statements. use `.matches("\?")` (that's a regex, but one character is enough. You can also use `.indexOf('?') > -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few issues there

- nextLine() actually returns the next line and moves on the scanner, so you'll need to read once instead
- indexOf returns an int, not a boolean, I'm guessing you're more use to C++? You can use any of the following instead:

  - indexOf("?") >=0
  - contains("?")
  - matches("\?") etc.
- please follow the java ways and use camelCase for vars...

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("foo.txt"));
    List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> other = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.contains("?")) {
            questions.add(line);
        } else {
            other.add(line);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(questions);
    System.out.println(other);
}
```

foo.txt

```
line without question mark
line with question mark?
another line
```

Comment: And yes, I'm usually coding in C++. Object oriented programming is bringing down my groove